# Cmake does not configure the files

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to create a `CMakeLists.txt` to configure some files but it is not working properly,

here is my code,

```
set (MDIR "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/share/models")
configure_file ( "include/CLMParameters.h.in" "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR} /CLMParameters.h" )
```

here is the code in the header file,

```
# code ....

wSizeCurrent = wSizeLarge;

defaultModelLoc = @mdir@/main.txt;

XLeftOffset = 100;
XRightOffset = 100;

# more code and so on
```

I was expecting it to change `@mdir@` to my defined path, but what I get is just,

```
defaultModelLoc = /main.txt;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CMake variable names are case-sensitive. Use `@MDIR@` in the file to be configured.